# Is there a builtin library for moving and replacing a file?

Tags: micropython

As the title suggests, is there a builtin library for moving a file and replacing an existing file if it exists?

I tried os.rename(path1, path2), but that doesn't seem to handle overwriting existing files.

Working with a pycom gpy, if that matters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX semantics require overwriting the target file in this case (and even atomically). So, "pycom gpy" seems to have a bug (or misfeature) in that regard. As a workaround, you can remove the target file with `os.remove(path2)` before rename.